# Manipulation Events In WebView UWP

Tags: windows, webview, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

Manipulation events do not get triggered in webview. I came across this thread which tells works are going on to bring this.
[Windows Dev Uservoice link](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/15260955-enable-manipulation-events-for-webview)

Can anyone update the status for this and update whether there's a solution for this or it might not be possible at all?

Comment: There is no new build since known issue submitted.  You may need to wait for new build coming if it is fixed. By testing on my side, the webview manipulation events can be triggered on a mobile emulator by manipulate the webview’s marginal.

Comment: manipulate the marginal?? what do you mean

Comment: what's the edge sdk link to manipulation events?